# Why is GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE different for POT and NPOT Textures?

Tags: opengl, textures

In the image below, the left texture is a POT texture – if the texture coordinates go beyond the [0,1] the edge pixels repeat. That is what I would expect.

[image: pot vs npot texture]

But the same exact code when rendering a NPOT texture does not extend the edge pixels on the right edge *only*.

Why do they behave differently?

[EDIT]

To ensure I wasn't making some other mistake, I replaced the rendering code with simple test code.

```
    GLboolean glEnable2d = 0;
GLboolean glEnableRect = 0;
glGetBooleanv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, &glEnable2d);
glGetBooleanv(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, &glEnableRect);

if (texWidth == 1.0 && texHeight == 1.0) {
    if (glEnableRect) {
        printf("GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB is ENABLED!\n");
    }
    printf("TEX 2D: width = %.3f, height = %.3f\n", texWidth, texHeight);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
} else {
    if (glEnable2d) {
        printf("GL_TEXTURE_2D is on!\n");
    }
    printf("TEX RECT: width = %.3f, height = %.3f\n", texWidth, texHeight);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
}

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

if (drawBeyondEdge) {

    glTexCoord2f(0.0 * texWidth, 1.0 * texHeight);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1.0 * texWidth, 1.0 * texHeight);
    glVertex3f(+1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1.0 * texWidth, 0.0 * texHeight);
    glVertex3f(+1.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(0.0 * texWidth, 0.0 * texHeight);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f);

} else {

    glTexCoord2f(-1.0 * texWidth, 2.0 * texHeight);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(2.0 * texWidth, 2.0 * texHeight);
    glVertex3f(+1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(2.0 * texWidth, -1.0 * texHeight);
    glVertex3f(+1.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(-1.0 * texWidth, -1.0 * texHeight);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, +1.0f, 0.0f);

}

glEnd();
```

And this is the result it produced, with the POT texture on the left and the NPOT texture on the right.

[image: pot vs npot output from simple test code]

Comment: maybe a mistake in specifying the texture?

Comment: What is your GPU type? driver? did you try it with other GPU/driver ?

Comment: Are you sure that there is no column of black pixels in the texture?

Comment: To answer your questions: (1) Checking for a row of black pixels was the first thing I did -- the image goes right to the edge. (2) To ensure that I did not make a mistake with the texture coordinates, I replaced the rendering bit with some test code. See my edit in the main post and an image showing the result. (3) The GPU I'm using is an AMD Radeon 6750M on a Mac Book Plus.

Comment: OK. I have answered my own question. I was using Apple Client Storage because I am uploading live video to this texture. As recommended here [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_texturedata/opengl_texturedata.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH407-SW24) I had rounded the width of the texture up to a multiple of 32 bytes, filling the extra bit on the right with black. The problem doesn't appear for NPOT textures because they are always a multiple of 32 bytes if they are a least 8 pixels wide.

Comment: You can make this an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I have answered my own question. I was using Apple Client Storage because I am uploading live video to this texture. As recommended by the [Apple Client Storage Recommendations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_texturedata/opengl_texturedata.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH407-SW24) I had rounded the width of the texture up to a multiple of 32 bytes, filling the extra bit on the right with black. The problem doesn't appear for NPOT textures because they are always a multiple of 32 bytes if they are a least 8 pixels wide.